# Problema con un Dado AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, programación-móvil

estoy haciendo una aplicacion de DND para Android y me esta surgiendo un error que no controlo el por qué aparece.
La idea es que el usuario escoja cuantos caras tiene el dado y cuantos dados desea lanzar.

El error que me aparece es este:

"E/xample.proyect: No package ID e9 found for ID 0xe9126a0f."

En este caso ha sido al lanzar dos dados de seis caras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
 public void lanzardados(View view) {
        String value = etcarasdeldado.getText().toString();
        int carasdeldado = Integer.parseInt(value);
        String value1 = etdadosalanzar.getText().toString();
        int dadosalanzar = Integer.parseInt(value);
        int resultado = 0;
        int resultado1 = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        try {
            if (carasdeldado <= 0 && dadosalanzar <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No pueden ser numeros negativos o iguales a 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < dadosalanzar; ++i) {
                    resultado = rand.nextInt()*carasdeldado+1;
                    resultado1 +=  resultado;
                    etfinal.setText(resultado1);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable `resultado1` es de tipo `int`, si tratas de usar un entero como parámetro en el método `setText()` de tu `EditText` este valor se tomara como el id de una vista en tu proyecto pero esto no es en realidad así, es por esta razón que obtienes el error:

> No package ID e9 found for ID

Convierte el valor `int` a `String` para usarlo dentro del método `setText()`, puedes usar:

```
etfinal.setText(String.valueOf(resultado1));
```

o también

```
etfinal.setText(""+resultado1);
```